# How to remove last sentence in text with imacros eval using regex

Tags: javascript, regex, eval, imacros

I tried to remove last sentence in extracted text using JavaScript replace method with regex. I check regex - it correct. But imacros default on code line which is right for most cases.

```
SET !VAR1 EVAL("var s=\'{{!EXTRACT}}\'; s.replace(/\.[^\.]+\.?$/,'.');")
```

Answer (score 1):

try to use this

> SET !VAR1 EVAL("var s=\'{{!EXTRACT}}\'; s.replace(/.[^.]+.?$/,'.');")

I used the web page

https://regex101.com/

to find the issue.

best regards
Patrick